# Web page (razor) signalr webmatrix error

Tags: razor, signalr, webmatrix

Hi I am designing a website for chatting and video conferencing with asp web page, signalr using webmatrix but i had this exception.

> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Core, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=451ee5fa653b377d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:

Comment: Check out fusion logging - it will show you where it has looked for that assembly.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1527249/2319909